# Bigquery Failed to Parse bq_parse_files with bq_table_download?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I have bigquery some table. bq_table_download functions work for most of the table, however, it shows failed to parse errors with 1 table.

```
bigrquery::bq_auth()
sql_query=paste0("select * from `project_id.dataset.table_name`")
bq_table_ext=bq_table_download(bq_project_query(project_id, sql_query))
```

In order to solve this I have also used as suggested bq_table_download have download quota limit.

```
options(scipen = 20)
```

However, still, I am unable to figure what is an issue.
Here is snapshot of error code

```
Error in bq_parse_files(schema_path, c(path_first_chunk, chunk_plan$dat$path),  : 
  Failed to parse '/tmp/Rtmpjd5eQN/bq-download-8650ad590.json'
Calls: ... master_table_base -> bq_table_download -> bq_parse_files
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In writeBin(result$content, con) : problem writing to connection
2: In writeBin(result$content, con) : problem writing to connection
Execution halted
```

Comment: Can you update your post and share a complete sample of the problematic dataset? Just so the community members can easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: Datasets contains categorical and numerical values with 27 columns and 1,604,375 rows. Table size is 885.48 MB. I have also test in ```check_table=bq_table_download(bq_project_query(project_id, sql_query),page_size=100,max_connection=1)``` Still having issues

Comment: You can try getting a few rows (probably 10 rows) and check if the error still persist. If error persists, you can try posting the 10 rows that produced the error if possible.

Comment: It works fine with 100 K rows, but the issues is after this we are get that error. This same function bq_table_download works wiht 6,606,000 rows with another bigquery table. But didn't understand the limitation of this function with specific table.

Comment: Will just post your created git issue here for reference. https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/issues/464